# You may take me for granted, but in every gadget I am planted

Tags: riddle

You use me everyday 
Without me you won’t know the way ️
You may take me for granted 
But in every gadget I am planted

**Who am I?**

Comment: This seems like it could have many good and many great answers. Does the intended answer fit significantly better than all others?

Answer (score 1):

> I think you may be electricity or electronics (if the way not to get lost is to use a GPS).

Comment: Gadgets aren't necessarily electronic or electric.

Answer (score 1):

Another wild guess

> A purpose.

> We daily do things with a purpose.
>  Where we go depends on the purpose of an errand.
>  We take for granted our life has a purpose ... usually.
>  A gadget is a device for a specific purpose.

Answer (score -1):

> the answer is a port. every electronic has a port(usb/charging/connection)

Comment: I wouldn't say you necessarily need a port to know the way

Answer (score -2):

> You use matter everyday
>  Without matter you won’t know the way
>  You may take matter for granted
>  But in every gadget matter is planted